# Trying to get DIV to take 100% of viewport (div escapes parent div)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have several nested DIVs. I want my second Div to take up 100% of the viewport regardless of size of the screen. I have two images in this div and two buttons. The buttons get pushed outside of the parent div whenever the screen gets "to big or to small".

I've tried moving the "topContainerBtns" into the "topPage" div but that seems to mess with the styling quite a bit.

```css
html,
body {
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.topContainer {
  height: 100vh;
}

#crunchyFace {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: auto;
  width: 20%;
}

#topPage {
  margin: 2%;
  padding-top: 5em;
  padding-bottom: 10em;
}

.parallax {
  background-image: url('../assets/img/CrunchSoft/backgroundColor.png');
  height: 25%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="topContainer row">
    <div id="topPage" class="col-sm-11 col-xl-11 col-lg-11">
      <img id="crunchyFace" src="https://dummyimage.com/3035x371/000/fff" alt="Crunchy" class="img-responsive" />
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" class="img-fluid img-responsive" />
    </div>
    <div id="topContainerBtns" class="text-center col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Cost Calculator</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Request a Requsition</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="parallax"></div>
</div>
```

On my bigger monitor, the picture looks great. Then I drag it over to my small laptop monitor and the buttons end up outside of the parent DIV. I need "topContainer" to take up 100% of the view port regardless of the screen size.

Edit: I don't think the code snippet explains perfectly what the problem is, but how far away the buttons are from the bottom picture close to what I mean.

Comment: I moved your existing code into a snippet but it would be easier for others to help you if it was a functional one. You can add working image URLs etc to make your problem easier to understand.

Comment: How can I added a working snippet? Thank you.

Comment: @MaxTaylor-Hayden your images obviously will not load from your local assets folder in the snippet. Please reference images that will represent what you are trying to do, or create divs that show the same.

Comment: you have it, edit it  now ;)  , for the image , you can use the http://dummyimage.com site or any similar website to insert fake image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The width isn't set, so how do you expect the container to scale across the whole viewport.

set `.topContainer` width to `width:100%;`

Comment: I have since, set my width: 100% and still on a smaller screen, the buttons escape outside of the parent div.

Comment: in which browser is this in? because it is still inside the div. Not exactly sure what your problem is because you did not explain in enough detail. You might have a different understanding of a element inside a ```div``` as far as I know. Please post a image of how you want it, so we know what is the precise problem you have.

Comment: Give the first ```div``` a ```class```. Then set it's ```width``` to ```100%``` . still not exactly sure what your problem is. because everything is inside the div, i verified this by using inspect. And nothing is creating a horizontal scroll, so not sure what your problem is.